# Passing CXXFLAGS to make has no effect

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, gnu-make

I am trying to compile some software with `make` on Ubuntu 16.04. However, it fails with the error:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file 
requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This 
support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

A quick websearch shows that compiler options can be passed to `make` either by

```
export CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11"
```

or

```
make CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11"
```

None of those options have worked. I have also tried with deleting everything in the build folder and starting from scratch. The error still persists.

How can I pass CXXFLAGS to `make` ?

Comment: It's probably inside the `Makefile` that's not picking it up. Make sure non-implicit rules include `$(CXXFLAGS)` on the compile commands (if it's not an implicit rule, make won't include it automatically).

Comment: Was the Makefile created from a configure program of some kind? It may be necessary to pass the CXXFLAGS to the configuration program as it may hardwire the flags it was given (or defaulted to) into the Makefile.

Comment: @BowieOwens Yes, indeed it was. I used `cmake` to populate the dedicated build folder. I then modified the configuration scripts for `cmake` and got it working. Still a bit confused though, why `make` would not accept the the flags passed as described above.

Comment: Merely passing a variable definition to `make` will not make its value
be used in recipes unless the recipes in the makefile *use* it.
If your makefile was generated by CMake, then your CMakeLists was
at fault.